# How do I get php-win to work with Zend Server?

Tags: php, zend-server

I recently installed Zend Server CE but I can't get php-win to do anything. When I run a cmd script using the standard php call it works perfectly but any call using php-win just fails to do anything. No output; nothing.

For example:

```
php C:\path\to\script
```

The above works.

But the below doesn't do anything:

```
php-win c:\path\to\script
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the PHP manual:

> As of PHP 5, a new php-win.exe file is distributed. This is equal to the CLI version, except that php-win doesn't output anything and thus provides no console (no "dos box" appears on the screen). This behavior is similar to php-gtk. You should configure with --enable-cli-win32.

I.e. php-win is not supposed to produce output. It can do other things though - write to the disk, to the database, etc. So if you want to check it, write script like:

```
 <?php
 file_put_contents("a", "aaa");
```

and see if the file appears.